# Custom Node type template issue

Tags: nodes, theming, entities

I have a created a content type with some fields like title,date,description etc. My issue is node block template file is working.

Content type(machine name) is - **event**

I have also created a special template file for this page

-- **event.tpl.php**

```
 <div id="container">
<div id="leftright_left"><?php print $left; ?> </div>
<div id="leftonly_content"> <?php print $messages; ?>
  <?php if($node->title != 'Welcome' && !$is_front): ?>
  <?php print $breadcrumb; ?> <?php print $tabs; ?>
  <?php  print $content; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I have created main template in the following file. So **$content** variable should be replaced with the following code.

Node block file name is -- **node-event.tpl.php**

```
    <div class="event_content" style="width:100%;">
<p class="word-wrap"><strong>Event Date</strong>:
  <?php  
$event_date=$node->field_event_date[0]['value']; 

 print $node->field_event_date[0]['view'] ?>
</p>
<?php if($node->field_event_end_date[0]['view'] != "") { ?>
<p class="word-wrap"><strong>Event Last Date</strong>: <?php print $node->field_event_end_date[0]['view'] ?> </p>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($node->field_event_time[0]['view'] != "") { ?>
<p class="word-wrap"><strong>Event Time</strong>: <?php print $node->field_event_time[0]['view'] ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($node->field_event_location[0]['view'] != "") { ?>
<p class="word-wrap"><strong>Location</strong>: <?php print $node->field_event_location[0]['view'] ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($node->field_event_price[0]['view'] != "") { ?>
<p class="word-wrap"><strong>Pricing</strong>: <?php print $node->field_event_price[0]['view'] ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($node->field_event_discount[0]['view'] != "") { ?>
<p class="word-wrap"><strong>Early Bird Discount</strong>: <?php print $node->field_event_discount[0]['view'] ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($node->field_event_group_discount[0]['view'] != "") { ?>
<p class="word-wrap"><strong>Group Discount: </strong><?php print $node->field_event_group_discount[0]['view'] ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($node->field_event_group_discount[0]['view'] != "") { ?>
<p class="word-wrap"><strong>Pre Requisite:</strong> <?php print $node->field_event_prerequisites[0]['view'] ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<span class="body_content"><?php print $node->content['body']['#value']; ?></span> </div>
```

But this is not working. Instead, its giving generalized unaligned output.

Please help me in getting solve this issue.

-
Thanks

Syam

Comment: Can you please clarify what's not working? Are you sure you've named your templates correctly? Are you sure it shouldn't be `node--event.tpl.php`? Have a look at this [page about theme hook suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) for Drupal 7 or [this page for Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/1089642).

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache after creating `node-event.tpl.php`?

Comment: Hampusn, Can you please explain how to clear cache. I am a newbie to Drupal !

Comment: Log in. Go to `admin/settings/performance` click **Clear cached data**.

Comment: Hampusn, You are amazing. Its working pretty fine :) . Thanks alot. I struggled for more than 6 hours to solve this.

Comment: Glad I could help :)